# Unbound method TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've just been reading an article that talks about implementing a parser in python:
http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm

The general idea behind the code is described in this paper: http://mauke.hopto.org/stuff/papers/p41-pratt.pdf

Being fairly new to writing parsers in python so I'm trying to write something similar as a learning exercise. However when I attempted to try to code up something similar to what was found in the article I am getting an `TypeError: unbound method TypeError`. This is the first time I've encountered such an error and I've spent all day trying to figure this out but I haven't solved the issue. Here is a minimal code example (in it's entirety) that has this problem:

```
import re

class Symbol_base(object):
    """ A base class for all symbols"""
    id = None # node/token type name
    value = None #used by literals
    first = second = third = None #used by tree nodes

    def nud(self):
        """ A default implementation for nud """
        raise SyntaxError("Syntax error (%r)." % self.id)

    def led(self,left):
        """ A default implementation for led """
        raise SyntaxError("Unknown operator (%r)." % self.id)

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.id == "(name)" or self.id == "(literal)":
            return "(%s %s)" % (self.id[1:-1], self.value)
        out = [self.id, self.first, self.second, self.third]
        out = map(str, filter(None,out))
        return "(" + " ".join(out) + ")"


symbol_table = {}
def symbol(id, bindingpower=0):
    """ If a given symbol is found in the symbol_table return it.
        If the symblo cannot be found theni create the appropriate class
        and add that to the symbol_table."""
    try:
        s = symbol_table[id]
    except KeyError:
        class s(Symbol_base):
            pass
        s.__name__ = "symbol:" + id #for debugging purposes
        s.id = id
        s.lbp = bindingpower
        symbol_table[id] = s
    else:
        s.lbp = max(bindingpower,s.lbp)
    return s

def infix(id, bp):
    """ Helper function for defining the symbols for infix operations """
    def infix_led(self, left):
        self.first = left
        self.second = expression(bp)
        return self
    symbol(id, bp).led = infix_led

#define all the symbols
infix("+", 10)
symbol("(literal)").nud = lambda self: self #literal values must return the symbol itself
symbol("(end)")

token_pat = re.compile("\s*(?:(\d+)|(.))")

def tokenize(program):
    for number, operator in token_pat.findall(program):
        if number:
            symbol = symbol_table["(literal)"]
            s = symbol()
            s.value = number
            yield s
        else:
            symbol = symbol_table.get(operator)
            if not symbol:
                raise SyntaxError("Unknown operator")
            yield symbol
    symbol = symbol_table["(end)"]
    yield symbol()

def expression(rbp = 0):
    global token
    t = token
    token = next()
    left = t.nud()
    while rbp < token.lbp:
        t = token
        token = next()
        left = t.led(left)
    return left

def parse(program):
    global token, next
    next = tokenize(program).next
    token = next()
    return expression()

def __main__():
    print parse("1 + 2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    __main__()
```

When I try to run this with pypy:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_main.py", line 72, in run_toplevel
  File "parser_code_issue.py", line 93, in <module>
    __main__()
  File "parser_code_issue.py", line 90, in __main__
    print parse("1 + 2")
  File "parser_code_issue.py", line 87, in parse
    return expression()
  File "parser_code_issue.py", line 81, in expression
    left = t.led(left)
TypeError: unbound method infix_led() must be called with symbol:+ instance as first argument (got symbol:(literal) instance instead)
```

I'm guessing this happens because I don't create an instance for the `infix` operations but I'm not really wanting to create an instance at that point. Is there some way I can change those methods without creating instances?

Any help explaining why this is happening and what I can do to fix the code is greatly appreciated!

Also is this behaviour going to change in python 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to create an instance of the symbol in your `tokenize()` function; when not a number, yield `symbol()`, not `symbol`:

```
else:
    symbol = symbol_table.get(operator)
    if not symbol:
        raise SyntaxError("Unknown operator")
    yield symbol()
```

With that one change your code prints:

```
(+ (literal 1) (literal 2))
```

Comment: This gets rid of the `TypeError` but appears to have changed the behaviour of the program. `parse("1 + 2")` is now returning `None` as opposed to the desired result of `3`

Comment: @shuttle87: That's because `expression()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: good catch, I think I didn't copy that code over to the minimal example properly. This is a bug that was not in the original code and is unrelated to the problem I am asking about. So I edited the question with the correct code.

Comment: @shuttle87: Your symbol lookups should probably return *instances* of the symbol objects, though.

Comment: Yes, they definitely should, my intention was to do just that but I think I messed that up somehow.

Comment: @shuttle87: off the train, and a closer look shows me what you are really trying to do; the fix is much simpler, as you forgot to create an instance of the symbol class in one place.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't bound new function to the instance of your object.

```
import types

obj = symbol(id, bp)
obj.led = types.MethodType(infix_led, obj)
```

See accepted answer to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object)

Comment: While my problem was caused by something else this was good to know about.